# The request specifies conflicting certificate templates : Web Server/Copy of User

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, certificate

I have an enterprise CA and I duplicate a User certificate template for authentication, and when I submit a certificate from web enrollment I got this error message: `Certificate Request Denied`.

> Your certificate request was denied.
>   Your Request Id is 63. The disposition message is "Denied by Policy Module 0x80094802, The request specifies conflicting certificate templates : Web Server/Copy of User."

I already give read and roll permission to authenticated users in Copy of User Certificate template.

Any idea to solve this issue?

Below I attached screenshots of Windows Event log and error message for better understanding.

Windows Event log:
[image]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

Error message:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. I think can be because CN isn't included in SAN or the first certificate has done with ssl template (server authentication) and renew is done with ssl and client authentication. 
Regards,